Question about relativistic mass and momentum transfer of Light
How can we reconcile the concept of inertia, typically associated with mass, with the behavior of light or electromagnetic waves, which lack classical mass but still exhibit resistance to changes in motion, as evidenced by phenomena such as momentum transfer and wave properties?


How can we reconcile the concept of inertia, typically associated with mass

Every Newtonian invocation of mass is actually an invocation of energy. Inertia is not due to mass. It is due to energy, just that the energy that we call rest mass energy vastly dwarfs the kinetic energy that was accessible at the time.
Similarly, gravitation is not due to mass. It is due to the energy and momentum content distribution in spacetime. Prior to our modern understanding, prominent gravitational curvature had only been seen to be dominated by the rest mass energy term, and so people misunderstood it to mean that gravity depended upon mass.
It has never been. There is no modern confusion as to why inertia and gravity are the same---they are the same because both of them are really tracking the quantity we call energy, and since they are tracking the same thing, obviously they will have to be the same.

with the behavior of light or electromagnetic waves, which lack classical mass but still exhibit resistance to changes in motion, as evidenced by phenomena such as momentum transfer and wave properties?

Photons carry energy and momentum just fine, and in agreement with what you would expect if you understood that waves carry energy and momentum.

There simply is a relationship, the Einstein's mass-energy-momentum relation, stating that $$E=+\sqrt{(mc^2)^2+(\vec pc)^2}$$ and in this equation, the invariant mass, rest mass, the only mass worth talking about, $m$, is a constant that identifies which fundamental (anti-)particle we are referring to. This formula is perfectly well applicable, be $m>0$ or $m=0$. We tend to think of this as the momentum $\vec p$ being a completely free independent variable to be anything we like, and then the energy $E$ is fixed by the above relation.
Be careful, $\vec p\neq m\vec v$; instead, $\vec v=c^2\,\vec p/E$

The best way to reconcile inertia in relativity is to not use inertia, which means not using the relativistic mass
$$m\rightarrow \gamma m $$,
(I won't even use as equals sign and assign a relativistic mass variable, nor demote $m$ to $m_0$, $m$ is $m$, the mass, Forget about relativistic mass)
which ppl liked because it made
$$E=mc^2$$
and
$$ p = mv $$
work for all velocities, but that is not worth it.
Rather:
$$ E = \gamma m $$
$$ p = \gamma m v $$
are correct. Note also that the momentum per unit energy is:
$$ \frac p E = \frac{\gamma mv}{\gamma m} = v $$
so photons, with $v=c$, carry the most bang for the buck (read: momentum per energy).
Mass is energy that reduces momentum, at constant energy.

I do not really see the problem. Just don't think about a photon as a massive ball. Photons are massless particles but have momentum ($p=\hbar k$) which can be transfered. See the principle behind solar sails for a practical example. As for the resistance against change in motion you might give some examples. I would say a photon travels in a straight line with constant velocity $c$ (in vacuum) due to the lack of/magnitude of interactions. So maybe just don't think about inertia (which I think is a quite vague concept in itself, at least very seldomly treated in physics classes), maybe that is the best way to reconcile anything.

You may choose to define the photon mass as "relativistic mass", $m=E/c^2$ (concrete, old school), or "invariant mass", $m=0$ for a free photon (abstract, fashionable). In either case, the photon carries the same momentum, you simply have to adjust your other math to be consistent.
Weirdy, "invariant mass" comes and goes: "invariance" is about reference frames, not physical processes. A photon in a box has invariant mass equal to its relativistic mass, not zero. Go figure...
